# python3 taking a combination of int and string

Tags: python, input, split

Input Format:
first line: an integer 'n'
next 'n' lines: an integer and a string with space in between
Example:

```
20
0 ab
6 cd
0 ef
6 gh
4 ij
0 ab
6 cd
0 ef
6 gh
0 ij
4 that
3 be
0 to
1 be
5 question
1 or
2 not
4 is
2 to
4 the
```

Is there a better way to take the input and store it in a list.
My code:

```
n=int(input())
l=list(map(lambda i:(int(i[0]),i[1]),[[i for i in input().split()] for j in range(n)]))
```

Comment: "better" in what sense ?

Comment: first I am taking all input and storing it in a  list and then i am using map(). Is there a way to get each line proprocessed and then store in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
n = int(input())
final_data = [[int(a), b] for a, b in [input().split() for i in range(n)]]
```